# How can I alias a dot string (e.g. '...' to '../..')?

Tags: command-line, bash, cd, alias

I'm trying to have a shortcut for going back a few dirs. Something like `"cd ...." == "cd <number of dots - 1> * '../'"`

1. I tried doing alias '...'='../..' && cd ... but got ***"No such file or directoy"***
2. I then tried doing alias '...'='../..' but got ***"invalid alias name"***
3. I guess I can create a function: `function bla { for i in $(seq $(($1 - 1))); do cd ../; done;  }; bla 3` but that seems less elegant (and also I cd ../ one in a time which is bad (`cd -` won't have the desired effect for example) but I can concat the strings and only cd at the end)

My questions are: How to solve (1) & (2) and is there a neater way for this?

Comment: I did a [function](https://github.com/bac0n/bash_completion/blob/master/bash_aliases) doing almost exactly what you ask for, you only need the cd function, but it is nice with bash-completion.

Comment: Neither of the suggested duplicates seem to address the actual issue here: creating aliases with multiple dots (especially not arbitrarily many, as my answer does).

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend

```
alias '...'='cd ../..'
```

With that, you can simply type `...` and go up two directories (even easier than `cd ...`!)

You can even make a whole set of them:

```
alias '..'='cd ..'
alias '...'='cd ../..'
alias '....'='cd ../../..'
alias '.....'='cd ../../../..'
```

...and so on

Alternately, if you want to skip all that typing, this will create all the aliases up to 100 directories:

```bsh
alias_str=".."
cmd_str="cd .."
for i in $(seq 1 100);
do
    alias ${alias_str}="$cmd_str"
    alias_str="$alias_str."
    cmd_str="$cmd_str/.."
done
```

Comment: It's nice, however it's not scalable (which is fine in this case, I guess)

Comment: @CIsForCookies I added a more scalable solution that works up to 100 directories (or whatever number you use in the `for` loop).

Answer (score 3):

Use a function like this:

```sh
...() { 
  b=".."
  # check that the argument is a number
  if [[ ! "$1" =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]; then
    echo "Bad argument."
  else
    # if no arguments, or it is 1, just back 1 dir
    if [[ $# -eq 0 || "$1" -eq 1 ]]; then 
      cd ..
    else 
      for i in $(seq 1 "$1"); do
        b+="/.."
      done
      cd "$b"
    fi
  fi
}
```

So you pass the argument of how many dirs you want to go back. Example:

```
$ cd /home/user/Foo/bar

/home/user/Foo/bar$ ... 2

/home/user/$
```

Comment: this is the exact same function I suggested in (3)

Comment: @CIsForCookies right! That happens for a too quick read, sorry.

Comment: @CIsForCookies I changed it to avoid multiple `cd`.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Just my opinion, but I think that a function is the better option. You have more control than having multiple aliases.

Comment: I agree multiple aliases are less than ideal